# semantic similarity for mix of languages

Tags: nlp, spacy, word2vec, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity

I have a database of several thousands of utterances. Each record (utterance) is a text representing a problem description, which a user has submitted to a service desk. Sometimes also the service desk agent's response is included. The language is highly technical, and it contains three types of tokens:

1. words and phrases in Language 1 (e.g. English)
2. words and phrases in Language 2 (e.g. French, Norwegian, or Italian)
3. machine-generated output (e.g. listing of files using unix command ls -la)

These languages are densely mixed. I often see that in one conversation, a sentence in Language 1 is followed by Language 2. So it is impossible to divide the data into two separate sets, corresponding to utterances in two languages.

The task is to find similarities between the records (problem descriptions). The purpose of this exercise is to understand whether some bugs submitted by users are similar to each other.

**Q: What is the standard way to proceed in such a situation?**

In particular, the problem lies in the fact that the words come from two different corpora (corpuses), while in addition, some technical words (like filenames, OS paths, or application names) will not be found in any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "standard way" - just things you could try.

You could look into word-embeddings that are aligned between langauges – so that similar words across multiple languages have similar vectors. Then ways of building a summary vector for a text based on word-vectors (like a simple average of all a text's words' vectors), or pairwise comparisons based on word vectors (like "Word Mover's Distance"), may still work with mixed-language texts (even mixes of languages within one text).

That a single text, presumably about a a single (or closely related) set of issues, has mixed language may be a blessing rather than a curse: some classifiers/embeddings you train from such texts might then be able to learn the cross-language correlations of words with shared topics. But also, you could consider enhancing your texts with extra synthetic auto-translated text, for any monolingual ranges, to ensure downstream embeddings/comparisons get closer to your ideal of language-obliviousness.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. After several experiments I developed a method which is simple and works pretty well. Rather than using existing corpora, I created my own corpus based on all the utterances available in my multilingual database. Without translating them. The database has 130,000 utterances, including 3,5 million of words (in three languages: English, French and Norwegian) and 150,000 unique words. The phrase similarity based on the meaning space constructed this way works surprisingly well. I have tested this method on production and the results are good. I also see a lot of space for improvement, and will continue to polish it. I also wrote this article [An approach to categorize multi-lingual phrases](https://ondata.blog/articles/categorize-multi-lingual-phrases/), describing all the steps in more detail. Critics or improvements welcome.